# Including Access-Control-Allow-Methods:* for only PUT requests

Tags: php, api, rest, cors

I am evaluating a REST API and I would like to know if including:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
```

In the `Response Headers` is correct when  the `Request Method` is only for `PUT`.

Also I am interested to understand if this can be a security risk or just a wrong practice.

[image: Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS]

Answer (score 0):

Technically, only `PUT` may not suffice. You probably need `OPTIONS` as well for the pre-flight request.

Generally speaking REST uses `PUT` to modify existing content. But we need to create content before we can modified. And so `POST` maybe should be allowed too? You decide.

For security concern, it is more on the code than allowed headers in my opinion.

Comment: Ok I understand your point but I believe DELETE it is not appropriate here, What do you think?

Comment: If we have a use case for `DELETE` we gonna put it somewhere anyway. Either in param, custom header or in Methods. if people can figure it out it is come down to how our code to handle those suspicious requests.

Comment: I am concerning about possible issue with Prefligh as desribed here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Comment: And here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests  thanks for your time on this.